# Which characters is the cast of Youkai Shoujo - Monsuga cosplaying as in the chapter 31 color cover?

Tags: youkai-shoujo-monsuga

Below is the color cover for chapter 31 of [**Youkai Shoujo - Monsuga**](http://myanimelist.net/manga/70775/Youkai_Shoujo_-_Monster_Girl).

[image]

The characters here are very clearly cosplaying as characters from other works; which characters are they cosplaying as?

Comment: I actually already know most of these characters except for the child in bird (kiwi) costume. To avoid making my question too long, and because most of the characters depicted here can be trivially reverse-searched, I decided to answer my question with the characters I know. Feel free to post a full-featured answer for the kiwi character without editing my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The child in bird (kiwi) costume looks like [Diao He Liao (Karyou Ten)](http://myanimelist.net/character/65407/Diao_He_Liao) from *Kingdom*.

[image: Character sketch]

[image: Ten when she wears a poncho made out of straw to hide her gender]

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, I do not recognize the child in what appears to be a [kiwi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiwi) costume, but here's a list of all the other characters.

From front to back (closest to farthest):

---

[image]
[**Mutsu**](http://kancolle.wikia.com/wiki/Mutsu) from [**Kantai Collection**](http://kancolle.wikia.com/wiki/Kancolle_Wiki)

---

[image]
[**Tomoe Mami**](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Mami) from [**Puella Magi Madoka Magica**](https://wiki.puella-magi.net/Puella_Magi_Madoka_Magica)

---

[image]
[**Yazawa Nico**](http://love-live.wikia.com/wiki/Yazawa_Nico) from [**Love Live!**](http://love-live.wikia.com/wiki/Love_Live!)

---

[image]
[**Makise Kurisu**](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Kurisu_Makise) from [**Steins;Gate**](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Steins;Gate_%28visual_novel%29)

---

[image]
[**Kasugano Sakura**](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Sakura) from [**Street Fighter**](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Street_Fighter_series)

---

[image]
Unknown [**kiwi**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiwi) child...

---

[image]
A [**Terraformar**](http://terraformars.wikia.com/wiki/Terraformar) from [**Terra Formars**](http://terraformars.wikia.com/wiki/Terra_Formars_TV)

---

[image]
[**Ada Wong**](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Ada) from [**Resident Evil**](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Resident_Evil_series)

---

[image]
[**Azrael**](http://blazblue.wikia.com/wiki/Azrael) from [**BlazBlue**](http://blazblue.wikia.com/wiki/BlazBlue_%28series%29)

---

On screen in the background:
**Kappa** as him-/herself.